# What verb do you use for when a professor or teacher is asking a student very difficult questions so that the student fail the exam?

Tags: word-choice

What verb do you use for descrihing the situation in which a professor or teacher is deliberately asking a student difficult questions so that the student can't pass it. The word for describing the situation in Russian is *валить*. It is a very informal word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not appear to be a special word for this particular situation. The situation is rather specialised and rare (spoken exams are not common below PhD level, and professors usually want their students to pass, not fail).

However the dictionary offers the [translation](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C) "cut (something) down", and this metaphor could work in English.

> I can't believe the questions that Professor Smith was asking. I'm sure he just wanted to cut me down. How am I supposed to know the air-speed velocity of an unladen sparrow!?

There is also "cut (somebody) down to size", an idiom meaning "Make someone realise that they are not as important or clever as they think they are".

> Katy is getting a bit too big for her boots.  Next test I'm going to ask her about semiotics. That should cut her down to size.